# How to add permission flags in deno compile?

Tags: permissions, runtime, deno

I created a script, and I want to use `deno compile --unstable [src]` to make it into an executable, but when I try to run the executable it says permission denied.

My question is is there a way to create the executable with permission flags like you can `deno install --flag [src]`.

Comment: *it says permission denied.* can you pls. show an example. I just tried with a short script that writes to a file. When I run it with deno run it needs `--allow-write`, but when I compile  with `deno compile` it can write a file and doesn't need any extra flags.

Comment: i think the issue comes from my scripts function. What it does is basicly create a new dir outside the root and add a bunch of files. I did this by using mkdir create or copy and in destination passing "../new dir"

Comment: not sure, but maybe it's just the operating system denying access to a certain paths? What do you use, Windows, Linux,  MacOS? For Deno the answer is currently there are no flags (at least in the current version) and you have access as if the flags are set.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delayed response. Im using mac, im tryint to test a few more things or else it might have smthing to do with the os

Comment: So iv tried switching from relative to absolute path by using `new URL` and now when i compile it and try to execute it it actually says i need to run again with the `--allow-write` flag, which makes no sense since its compiled.

Comment: I also used the same code as with the absolute path with `deno install` and the correct flags and it works but I still dont understand why compile doesnt work.

Comment: did you upgrade to Deno 1.7? On Deno 1.7 you need the flags during compile time, on Deno 1.6.3 not.

Comment: iv got the latest deno 1.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Deno 1.7.0](https://deno.land/) on, the  [compile](https://deno.land/manual@v1.7.0/tools/compiler) function has the same permission flags that we know from the run command.

Code that would need permissions (e.g. `--allow-write`) when run as a script, needs the same permissions given to the compile command.

For example, consider this short script that creates a file and writes text into it:

```js
const write = Deno.writeTextFile("./hello.txt", "Hello World!");
write.then(() => console.log("File written to ./hello.txt"));
```

Run as a script with `--allow-write`:

> > deno run --allow-write .\filewrite.ts
> File written to ./hello.txt

Compiled without `--allow-write`. The error message could be interpreted as if you need to apply the option to the created .exe, but in fact it needs to be applied during compilation:

> >deno compile --unstable .\filewrite.ts
> ...Emit filewrite
>
> >.\filewrite.exe
> error: PermissionDenied: write access to "./hello.txt", run again with the --allow-write flag

Compiled with the --allow-write flag:

> >deno compile --unstable --allow-write .\filewrite.ts
> ...Emit filewrite
>
> >.\filewrite.exe
> File written to ./hello.txt

The same is of course true for the `--allow-read` and `--allow-net` flags.

The previous Deno version (1.6.3) didn't have these compiler flags and behaved as if all permissions had been granted. See the [older revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65737359/2)